# Способы отслеживания недоступности микросервисов

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, микросервисы, spring-cloud

есть несколько микросервисов, которые написаны на `Spring Boot`, а для общения используется `Rabbit MQ`. Общаются они через поставщика и потребителя (функциональные интерфейсы `Supplier, Consumer`). Реализовано на `Spring Boot 3.2.0`.

Как взаимодействуют понятно (в документации `Spring Cloud Stream` говорится что нужно использовать функциональные интерфейсы).

Вопрос в том какие есть способы отслеживания/понимания того что потребитель (`Consumer`) недоступен/выключен? Т.е. поставщик отправил сообщение в очередь `Rabbit MQ`, но потребитель не прочитал его по какой-то причине.

Какие способы для отслеживания таких ситуаций, чем они отличаются и какой способ лучше, если можно кратко опишите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как это делается в Spring или Rabbit, но вообще у вас должна быть какая то система мониторинга, которая может

- принимать данные о состоянии хостов от агентов, установленных на хостах, такие как CPU / Диск / Память
- принимать данные от лоад балансеров, которые пингуют ваши хосты (у вас же есть deep ping или просто ping для проверки работы сервиса?)
- принимать данные по отправленным / обработанным запросам / сообщениям
- любые другие важные метрики, типа латенси, TPS, какие то ваши бизнес транзакции
- и прочее

Обычно по этим метрикам строят всякие дашборды с графиками, и если какие то из метрик начинают выпадать, проходить через пороговые значения, типа латенси большой или сервис не пингуется или отношение отправленных/обработанных сообщений выше какого то значения за период времени, то у вас должна быть система оповещения о таких проблемах, которая вам тикет сделает и вызовет кого надо.

Этот подход вообще не зависит от того, на чем у вас сами сервисы написаны. Пока вы можете отправлять метрики в систему мониторинга, вы можете в реальном времени следить за системой и своемременно реагировать.

Я не знаю, какие сейчас для этого актуальны инструменты, но вот это гуглится первым в поиске https://grafana.com/about/grafana-stack/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но мне кажется вы рассказали про общую схему мониторинга. А мне хотелось бы понять какие есть способы отследить что сообщение отправленное от одного микросервиса не дошло до второго при использовании брокера сообщений и spring cloud

Comment: я отвечал на вопрос `Вопрос в том какие есть способы отслеживания/понимания того что потребитель (Consumer) недоступен/выключен?`, но если вам надо делать трассировку сообщений, то это немного другое. Еще раз, я не спец, но для простых вещей я бы писал трейсы в логи, чтобы по traceid (aka correlation token) можно было бы отследить что происходит. Ну или гугол для реббита подсказывает это https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html